# Jsdom in browser produces 'parameter not of type node error' when using isEqualNode function

Tags: javascript, browserify, jsdom

Im using jsdom in the browser through browserify to be able to parse a html string into a document and use it within a web-worker:

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

function getDOM(string) {
  return new JSDOM(string).window;
};
```

And later on:

```
const jsdom = getDOM(body);

const jsdomH4 = jsdom.document.querySelector('h4');
const normalH4 = document.querySelector('h4');
```

`normalH4.isEqualNode(jsdomH4)` produces:

```
Error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'isEqualNode' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Am I doing something wrong or am I misunderstanding how jsdom is supposed to be used?

Also, I expected jsdom to behave the same way the normal document does. However, jsdom.document.querySelector('*') produces

```
Proxy {Symbol(impl): NodeListImpl}
  [[Handler]]: Object
  [[Target]]: NodeList
  [[IsRevoked]]: false
```

instead of a normal NodeList. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

jsdom does try to behave the same way a normal document does, but it *isn't* a browser DOM. You cannot use its data structures as if they are real DOM nodes.